# print a leap year in a certain format

Tags: java

i would like to print leap years in between two years given in a format like
'[2120,2024,2028]'.i want them with these commas and square brackets..kindly help me with this.in java
my program:

```
System.out.print("[");
for(int i=2017;i<=2040;i++)
{
    if(i%4==0)
    {
        System.out.print(i);
        if(i!=2040)
        {
            System.out.print(",");
        }       
    }
}
System.out.print("]");
```

if i change the value the comma is not working right

Comment: Note: if it's important to your code, leap years are [not just every four years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Gregorian_calendar).

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to put a comma before each number and not after. The effect is the same, but then you just need to make the first leap year a special case:

```
System.out.print("[");
boolean isFirstLeapYear = true;
for (int i=2017;i<=2040;i++) {
    if (i%4 == 0 && (i%100 != 0 || i%400 == 0)) {
        if (isFirstLeapYear) {
            isFirstLeapYear = false;
        } else {
            System.out.print(",");
        }
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
System.out.print("]");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more rules about leap year.

I suggest you to study this method and use it in your code:

```
boolean isLeapYear(year) {
    if (year % 400 == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```